# Ruby CSV + Spanish Characters: Encoding::UndefinedConversionError

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm getting an error `U+2014 from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1` when I try to use `send_data` with a CSV that has spanish characters:

model:

```
def self.books_data(books)
  csv = CSV.generate(:col_sep => "|", quote_char: '"') do |csv|
    ...
  end
  csv
end
```

controller:

```
def export_data
  ...
  data = CsvGenerator.books_data(@books)
  send_data(data.encode("iso-8859-1"), filename: "books_data_#{date}.csv", type: 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present') #<-- error occurs here
end
```

How would I fix this?

=== UPDATE ===

I think I semi-fixed it by replacing `.encode` with `.force_encoding`. However, I now have a lot of characters that don't look right:

Ex: The file contains:
`My Diary from Here to There / Mi diario de aqui hasta allÃ¡`

when it should look like

`My Diary from Here to There / Mi diario de aqui hasta allá`

Comment: Can you try `send_data(data.encode("iso-8859-1"), filename: "books_data_#{date}.csv", type: 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present', {:invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => '?'})`

Comment: It said syntax error. I think it was on the brackets around invalid `{}`. I removed them and tried again and there was no syntax error, but the error still came up when I tried to generate the file

Comment: Hey @zrl3dx I semi-fixed it. Any suggestions on the 2nd problem?

Comment: I think it's a problem with Open Office. When I print the string in the log it prints fine

Comment: Is there a reason you are encoding to iso-8859-1 – could you just send the response as UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String#force_encoding` should never be used as it just "tags" string with different encoding, while `#encode` does actual conversion.

The reason you're getting this error because, somewhere in your `data` you have a \u2014 character: "—". As the `String#encode` documentation states:

> raise Encoding::UndefinedConversionError for characters that are undefined in the destination encoding [...]

And if you check the iso map (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), there is no "—"
character in 8859-1. So to solve this, you need to remove those "invalid" characters from `data`.

Besides that, unless there are some specific reasons, you should avoid such conversions, and let CSV to be generated in utf-8 encoding.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel